# bash: dirname: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, git-bash, dirname

I'm trying to run a code I found online. There's a shell script in it, but every time I try to run it, it gives me this error:

```
bash: dirname: command not found
```

I've tried setting the PATH:

```
PATH=/home/user/bin
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm using Git Bash on a Windows 10 machine.

Here is what the shell script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

if [ $# -lt 1 ];
then
    echo "USAGE: $0 [-daemon] zookeeper.properties"
    exit 1
fi
base_dir=$(dirname $0)

if [ "x$KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:$base_dir/../config/log4j.properties"
fi

if [ "x$KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
    export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx512M -Xms512M"
fi

EXTRA_ARGS=${EXTRA_ARGS-'-name zookeeper -loggc'}

COMMAND=$1
case $COMMAND in
  -daemon)
     EXTRA_ARGS="-daemon "$EXTRA_ARGS
     shift
     ;;
 *)
     ;;
esac

exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class.sh $EXTRA_ARGS org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "$@"
`
```

Comment: `PATH` should be a list of directories; you are overwriting its value with a single directory. Did your problem start before or after you modified `PATH`?

Comment: Exactly how do you execute this script?

Comment: @chepner no my problem was already present before that

Comment: @glennjackman bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeper.properties

Comment: In a shell where `dirname` *does* work, run `type dirname`. You'll see it in a directory like `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. That means you need to have that directory among the entries in your PATH for it to keep working.

Comment: Similarly, `PATH=/home/user/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` is generally much more appropriate than `PATH=/home/user/bin`; what you're doing now tells your shell not to run any command *unless* it can be found in that single directory.

Comment: You almost never want to overwrite the value of `PATH`, only append or prepend values with something like `PATH=$PATH:/home/user/bin` or `PATH=/home/usr/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: ...stop setting a broken PATH value? Use a specific known-good value, like the one advised above (or one you can get by running `echo "$PATH"` in a shell where `dirname` works)?

Comment: (There's a lot more that's wrong with this script too -- using strings rather than arrays to build commands runs afoul of the issues described in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); and the lack of quoting means it'll fail when run in a directory name with spaces -- but best to start with the simple things)

Comment: ...re: aforementioned lack of quoting, run it through http://shellcheck.net/ to get the specific issues identified... but fix the PATH first.

Comment: (there's a whole lot of bad shell scripts circulating in the Java community, and the misuse of string variables -- which, depending on whether `eval` is used, either [can handle only a subset of possible argument values](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), *or* [introduce security vulnerabilities](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) -- for building commands is somewhat endemic -- too many wrapper scripts for Java programs written by copying wrappers for *other* Java programs, and nobody competent in shell ever gets involved to fix them).